# How to set up log file for Windows perl program

Tags: perl

I have huge Perl program on Windows 7. When I make :

```
system($cmd) > \\path_to\\logdir\\file.log
```

The programs dies without any messages.

How can I correctly set up log file?

Otherwise I am losing a lot of information with errors

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues in your script:

- If you had added

  ```
  use strict;
  use warnings;
  ```

  to your script it would have shown you the following errors with your first attempt:

  ```
  Useless use of numeric gt (>) in void context at ./foo line 9.
  Bareword "logfile" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at ./foo line 9.
  Bareword "txt" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at ./foo line 9.
  Execution of ./foo aborted due to compilation errors.
  ```
- You need to join the `$cmd` and the logfile's name into one string and give that string as a parameter to `system()`.
- You need to escape the backslashes because e.g. `\f` means *form feed* and `\l` means *lowercase next character*.
- When you want to redirect error messages, you usually want to redirect STDOUT **and** STDERR to a file.

To summarize:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $logfile = "\\path_to\\logdir\\file.log";
my $rc = system("$cmd > $logfile 2>&1");
if (!$rc) {
    warn "something went wrong\n";
}
```

This redirects both STDOUT and STDERR to the same file.

---

My answer refers to [this revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/37660280/1) of the question. Meanwhile someone edited the Q, added double backslashes `\\`, and thus invalidated the 3rd bullet above.

Answer (score -2):

Change 
system($cmd) > \path_to\logdir\file.log
to 
system($cmd > \path_to\logdir\file.log )

Comment: The same result. The program dies

Comment: program name and arguments

Answer (score -2):

oops.  
Change

```
system($cmd > \path_to\logdir\file.log )
```

to

```
system($cmd "> \path_to\logdir\file.log" )
```

Comment: inside $cmd is execution file cmd.exe. Now I got a message   " Can't spawn "cmd.exe": No such file or directory at G:\INVACCT\Perl\scripts\pfi_menu.pl line 295, <STDIN> line 12.

Comment: I suggest escaping the backslashes and using proper Perl syntax to concatenate strings. **Either** `system($cmd . "> \\path_to\\logdir\\file.log")` **or** `system("$cmd > \\path_to\\logdir\\file.log")`.

Comment: system("$cmd > \path_to\logdir\file.log" ). This ways it is working

Comment: Please fix your first answer (by [editing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37660613/edit) it) instead of posting a second answer.